# How to hide and display the upper part of TabWidget in Android

Tags: android

I am developing an application in android.I need to implement some functionality in TabWidget in Android, so that on clicking on some button the upper part of the Tab widget will be hide and its content only visible. Again on clicking of that button, the upper part can again visible. By this way , we can increase the resultant area to display its content.

Answer (score 6):

This ought to do it :

```
public void hideOrShowTabWidget(){
tabHost.getTabWidget().setVisibility((tabHost.getTabWidget().isShown() ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE));
}
```

updated with some nicer code :)